# Azure Blob client -> Get Zip Content (JAVA)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a scenario where I have to get the content of files from Azure blob, for .txt,.psv files I am able to get the content. But For zip files in a blob, Is there any way by which I can iterate over the files inside the zip and get the content for each file.

I am using the below code snippet

**

```
BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient= containerClient.getBlobClient("Archive.zip").getBlockBlobClient();
BinaryData data=blockBlobClient.downloadContent();
```

**

Comment: What do you mean by `I am not able to get the content`? Please edit your question and provide more details.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have a zip file in the azure blob,I want to access that file using java code and get the content of each file